# How to paste multiple values into multiple form inputs in one paste?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Say I copy

```
1 2 3 4
```

And then select an input field, when I paste it, it automatically puts 1 into the first field, 2 into the second field, 3 into the 3rd etc etc.

The values copied will separated by space, comma or a tab.

The form is simple html and I use PHP to insert into database, whatever language the solution is would be ok. I would image its jQUery, even direct me to a relevant jQuery plug in, if it exists.

Comment: Where are the fields? What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. You are expected to show your code attempts to solve your own issues and people help you fix **your code**. Also need details on validation that data length doesn't exceed available fields

Comment: fields would irrelevant, have tried nothing, because I don't what to try aside from googling esoteric phrases, I didn't assume it was a free code service, nor expecting code. My code here would be irrelevant for reasons previously mentioned. I'm sure no one one would begrudge a point in the right direction. I'm sure this thing I need has a name.

Comment: Start by learning how to split the string. There are lots and lots of resources on web on how to do that part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've commented the code line-by-line, hopefully that's enough. I have to head to work and I'll make any clarifying edits once I get there.

```js
$(function(){
  //run this on dom ready
  $('.paste-me').on('paste', function(e){
    //add the paste event to all of the paste-me classes
    var data1 = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0];
    //get the data transfer item of hte original clipboard data event.
    if(data1.kind == 'string' && data1.type=='text/plain'){
    //If it is a string and text/plain, move forward
      e.stopPropagation();
      //Stop the propagtion of this event
      data1.getAsString(function(s){
      //get the string contents of the clipboard item.
        s = s.split('\t');
        //split it by spaces
        $('.paste-me').each(function(i,item){
          //loop through each .paste-me item
          $(item).val( s[i] || '');
          //set the value from the split array, or an empty string if someone copy/pastes something too small to put a value in each item
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
```

### 2020 Edit

Since jQuery has fallen largely out of usage, in favor of a framework such as Angular, Vue, or React, I felt that this answer needed a bit of updating.

Below is a 100% Vanilla JS version that will work with the given HTML. Logically it follows the same steps as above, I just renamed some of the variables for readability. If you have any questions just ask.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const pasteMes = document.querySelectorAll('.paste-me');
  pasteMes.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('paste', e => {
      const data = e.clipboardData.items[0];
      if(data.kind == 'string' && data.type == 'text/plain') {
        data.getAsString(str => {
          str.split(/\s/).forEach((v, ind) => {
            pasteMes[ind] && (pasteMes[ind].value = v || '');
          })
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
<input class="paste-me" name="paste_me[]" type="text"/>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, just a quick question, I am trying to delimit using tabs but it seems `'\t'` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @AasimAzam I went to a google spreadsheet and wrote in `1 2 3 4` (into 4 different cells), changed the `split(' ')` to `split('\t')` and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: I tried pasting from excel, sheets and from simple text file, but to no avail. not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @AasimAzam I don't either -- that's really weird. I just tested it with text from an excel file and got the same results as I did from the google sheet. What operating system are you using? _Maybe_ that has something to do with it.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: That's weird, me too. Are you testing the snippet?

Comment: it works with the space, but not with the tab delimiter, even with the `'\t'` the space delimited paste works, put it in codepen and it doesn't work there either https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpRxVo except when I copy from a text file ....So its working but not working at the same time.

Comment: I went to the same link you just posted, made [this](https://imgur.com/K0qgctb) in a google sheet, copied the values, went to [your codepen](https://imgur.com/6f2zfp6), highlighted a field [and hit paste](https://imgur.com/b8WjTVI) and it's working as expected for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use tokenizer to acomplish this, then set the values (commonoly stored in a array) in the elementes you requiere.