# How to paste multiple values to textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have excel table, example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJJSC.png)

How i have copy all(ctrl+c) from table and insert(ctrl+v) data to **textarea** values in html "in one click", example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0558i.png)

I found this method, but it doesn't work in Firefox (for input, needed **textarea**) -> [How to paste multiple values into multiple form inputs in one paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981733/how-to-paste-multiple-values-into-multiple-form-inputs-in-one-paste/)

Please, can anyone help with a working method for the Firefox browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.